# Polars DataFrame enum and categorical type memory usage

Tags: python, python-polars

When I call `df.estimated_size()` on a `Categorical` or `Enum` column, it appears to have the same memory footprint as an `int32` of the same length, even though there are only four members in the category.

Is this memory size accurate? `shrink_to_fit()` doesn't improve the memory size.

1. Is there a way to reduce memory footprint of categoricals with small number of members?
2. aside: is there a better to convert int Ids to categoricals instead?
3. casting to str first?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at this point in time (January 2024), Polars only uses `u32` integers as `Categorical`/`Enum` keys. This may change in the future.

Comment: thanks, 
1. is there any docs examples explaining Enums and when / how to use them over Categoricals?  would I find this in pyarrow docs?

2. any suggestions how I can save memory on low cardinality columns apart from using my own int8 mapping table?