Python + Polars: how can I convert the values of a column with type `enum` into their integer ("physical") representation?
The polars user guide suggests that enums have a physical, integer representation.
Is it possible to access the integers associated with an enum value? For example, is there a nicer way to get the integer representation in the following example?
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

np.random.seed(556)

enum_vals = [
    "".join([chr(c_code) for c_code in np.random.randint(97, 123, 3)])
    for n in range(10)
]
enum_dtype = pl.Enum(pl.Series(enum_vals))

(
    pl.Series(
        "enum_vals",
        [enum_vals[x] for x in np.random.randint(0, len(enum_vals), 5)],
        dtype=enum_dtype,
    )
    .to_frame()
    .with_columns(
        enum_repr=pl.col("enum_vals").map_elements(
            lambda x: enum_vals.index(x), return_dtype=pl.Int64()
        )
    )
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ enum_vals ┆ enum_repr │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ enum      ┆ i64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ loo       ┆ 8         │
│ sby       ┆ 5         │
│ cqm       ┆ 3         │
│ cbn       ┆ 2         │
│ vtk       ┆ 9         │
└───────────┴───────────┘


For this, pl.Expr.to_physical exists. The documentation also lists the dtype of the underlying physical representation, which is pl.UInt32 for pl.Categorical / pl.Enum.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("enum_vals").to_physical()
)

shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ enum_vals │
│ ---       │
│ u32       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 8         │
│ 5         │
│ 3         │
│ 2         │
│ 9         │
└───────────┘


The answer linked in the question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77770318/3486684) suggests that we might be able to cast into an enum value into a UInt32, and this is indeed the case:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

seed = 556
print(f"seed={seed}")
np.random.seed(seed)

# print out all rows of our small table
pl.Config.set_tbl_rows(-1)
enum_vals = [
    "".join([chr(c_code) for c_code in np.random.randint(97, 123, 3)])
    for n in range(10)
]

enum_dtype = pl.Enum(pl.Series(enum_vals))
pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series(
            "enum_vals",
            [enum_vals[x] for x in np.random.randint(0, len(enum_vals), 5)],
            dtype=enum_dtype,
        )
    ]
).with_columns(enum_repr=pl.col("enum_vals").cast(pl.UInt32()))
# seed=556
#
# shape: (5, 2)
# ┌───────────┬───────────┐
# │ enum_vals ┆ enum_repr │
# │ ---       ┆ ---       │
# │ enum      ┆ i64       │
# ╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
# │ loo       ┆ 8         │
# │ sby       ┆ 5         │
# │ cqm       ┆ 3         │
# │ cbn       ┆ 2         │
# │ vtk       ┆ 9         │
# └───────────┴───────────┘

Surprisingly, directly casting to UInt64 (just as an example) does not work, so casting seems to be dependent on knowing a hidden implementation detail (which type is used for the physical representation of an enum value), and therefore not robust as a solution.
